# fseek and fscanf crash the program when used at the same time

Tags: c, scanf, fseek

So here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct dat{
    int broj;
    int sir;
}sir;

int main() {
    sir sir;
    FILE* fordat;
    int i=0;
    fordat = fopen("dattk.txt","w+");
    while(i<100) {
        i++;
        sir.broj = i;
        sir.sir=-i;
        fprintf(fordat,"%d %d", sir.broj, sir.sir);
    }

    // fseek(fordat,0,SEEK_SET);
    //rewind(fordat);    
    // fscanf(fordat,"%d %d",sir.broj,sir.sir);
    printf("%d% %d",sir.broj,c);
    fclose(fordat);

    return 0;
}
```

I am studying in C and made this simple example program of writing and reading from a file...

If I remove the comments from either `fseek` or `rewind` or `fscanf`, the program runs.
However, if I remove the comments from `fseek` AND `fscanf` the program compiles, but crashes on run.
Can't figure out why...

Answer (score 3):

Your `fscanf` call is broken - change:

```
fscanf(fordat,"%d %d",sir.broj,sir.sir);
```

to:

```
fscanf(fordat,"%d %d",&sir.broj,&sir.sir);
```

**Important: if you had compiled with warnings enabled (e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`) then the compiler would have helpfully pointed out this mistake to you, thereby saving you time and effort. Always enable compiler warnings and take heed of them.**

And one more thing: you have absolutely no error checking in your code - you should check for failure after `fopen` and all other calls which might potentially fail.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to add a sentence about error checking.